# Не подгружаются стили wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

создал свой виджет и пытаюсь пытаюсь подключить js файл вызовом функции

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', plugins_url().'/Car/qqw.js','','');
```

но ничего не происходит. В чем может быть проблема?
вот мой код виджета:

```
<?php
class btru_widget extends WP_Widget {

        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct(
            'btru_widget', 
            __('Widget', 'btru_widget_domain'), 
            array( 'description' => __( 'Виджет для вывода Model', 'btru_widget_domain' ), ) 
            );
        }
        public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
            $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
            echo $args['before_widget'];
            if ( ! empty($title ))
            echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
            $args = array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'Models',
            'get'           => 'all',
            'hide_empty'=>0
            );

            wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', plugins_url().'/Car/qqw.js','','');
            $terms = get_terms( $args );
            echo "<div id='accordion'>
            <h3>Models</h3>
            <div>";
            foreach( $terms as $term=>$WP_Term){
                echo "<p>".$WP_Term->name."</p>";     
            }
            echo "</div></div>";
            get_footer();
            echo $args['after_widget'];
        }
        public function form( $instance ) {
            if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
                $title = $instance[ 'title' ];
            }
            else {
                $title = __( 'Models', 'btru_widget_domain' );
            }
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>
            "><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label> 
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" 
            name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" 
            type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
        </p>
        <?php 
        }
        public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
            $instance = array();
            $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';
            return $instance;
        }
    }
    function btru_load_widget() {
        register_widget( 'btru_widget' );
    }
    add_action( 'widgets_init', 'btru_load_widget' );
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поздно!

wp_enqueue_script() заносит данные о скрипте во внутреннюю структуру WordPress и больше ничего не делает. Во время построение хедера и футера WordPress извлекает сведения о скриптах и прописывает их в хедере или (если это явно указано) в футере.

Ваша функция виджета запускается намного позже формирования хедера, поэтому скрипт и не попадает в код страницы.

Для того, чтобы запустить скрипт в футере, добавьте в вызов wp_enqueue_script пятый параметр true. Он отвечает за запуск в футере.

Или подключите скрипт, как положено. Уберите вызов из widget и добавьте в конец:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', 'my_script');
function my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', plugins_url() . '/Car/qqw.js');
}
```

Еще более правильно - убрать вызов из widget, добавить в __construct() строку

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', array( $this, 'my_script' ) );
```

а внутрь класса - функцию

```
public function my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', plugins_url() . '/Car/qqw.js');
}
```